# php sqlite3: are the database files closed automatically?

Tags: php, sqlite

Simple question that i couldn't find in the SQLite3::close() of the PHP manual: does PHP close sqlite databases when the script ends or do we need to call $db->close() ourselves all the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple answer: yes the file is closed at the end of the script. No need to do a close.

Comment: Thanks, i knew that other databases were autoclosed, wasn't sure about sqlite though.